# Search does not return any value in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My Controller:

```
def index
  @three_data = Threeddatum.all
  @three_data = @three_data.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
end
```

My model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.where("area LIKE ?", "%#{:search}%")
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_tag('/threeddata', method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>

<% @three_data.each do |data| %>
  <td><%= data.tape_id %></td>
  <td><%= data.media_type %></td>
  <td><%= data.area %></td>
  <td><%= data.aqdate %></td>
  <td><%= data.clocation %></td>
<% end %>
```

I have a field that has area code : SD-DWN-2309/5
But when I enter DWN in search field it does not return any row. 
Please help cause I really don't seem to find an issue  that's causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code `"%#{:search}%"` to `"%#{search}%"`

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.where("area LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @SouvikDas Please don't forget to accept the answer. You can do that by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: Done! I needed to wait 10 minutes before I could do so.